# Accessing list elements using double square brackets (python)

Tags: python

given a list, such as:

```
programming_languages = ['Python', 'Perl', 'R', 'Ruby']
```

What are the rules for using double square brackets [] ?

What I mean is if I try accessing `programming_languages[2][0]` or `programming_languages[3][0]` or `programming_languages[-1][-4]` for example, I'll get the element 'R'.

Thanks in advance for the help on clearing this up for me!

Edit: For some reason I did not realise the 'R' I get while accessing `programming_languages[3][0]` or `programming_languages[-1][-4]` is actually the 1st character of the 4th element in the list, and NOT the 2nd element 'R'.
Thanks for the answers below!

Comment: This might help shed light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square bracket syntax, like `programming_languages[n]` allow you to access the **nth** element.

```py
programming_languages = ['Python', 'Perl', 'R', 'Ruby']
programming_languages[0] # getting the first element in the list
# Python
```

When you use double square bracket, it means your element is a list-like object. If the first elements is `Python` then the first element would be `P`

```py
>>> programming_languages = ['Python', 'Perl', 'R', 'Ruby']
>>> # getting the first element in the list
>>> programming_languages[0] 
 Python
>>> # getting the first element in the string 'Python'
>>> programming_languages[0][0] 
 P
```

Comment: Thanks a alot for the explanation, I've just realised my source of confusion!

Comment: Accept the answer that enlight you the most.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, new to the site, unfamiliar yet with all of the features here

Comment: I guess you figure out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The square bracket operator isn't only defined on arrays, but also on strings.

```
a = programming_languages[1] # a = 'Perl'
print(a[0]) # P, which is the 0th letter of the string
print(a[3]) # l, which is the 3rd letter of the string
```

Comment: Understood, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

programming_languages is an array , so you are accessing each elemnt inside the array by first bracket, eg. : `programming_languages[0]`  which returns `'Python'`. noe in python , strings are considers as an array of characters , so the second bracket is picking the character whiting that string , so e.g :
`programming_languages[0][0]`  returns 'P'

Comment: Thanks, I just realised that the 'R' I get isnt the 3rd element but actually the 4th element's first character.